# Multiple functions in java

Tags: java, oop

From [this answer](http://www.careercup.com/question?id=5708733596303360):

There are two functions: One is public and calls the second one which has more arguments and is defined as private.

```
class Node{
    int data;
    ArrayList<Node> children = new ArrayList<Node>();
}

public static Node buildTree(int[] preOrder, int[] postOrder){
    if(preOrder == null || postOrder == null){
        throw new NullPointerException();
    }
    if(preOrder.length != postOrder.length){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    return buildTree(preOrder, 0, preOrder.length-1, postOrder, 0, postOrder.length -1);
}

private static Node buildTree(int[] preOrder, int preMin, int preMax, int[] postOrder, int postMin, int postMax){
    //construct the root;
    Node root = new Node();
    root.data = preOrder[preMin];

    //construct the child branches
    int preIndex = preMin + 1;
    int postIndex = postMin;
    while(preIndex <= preMax &&  postIndex <= postMax -1){
        //preOrder[preIndex] is now the root of the next child branch
        //find where preOrder[preIndex] occurs in postOrder
        int shift = 0;
        while(postOrder[postIndex + shift] != preOrder[preIndex]){
            shift++;
        }
        Node child = buildTree(preOrder, preIndex, preIndex + shift, postOrder, postMin, postMin + shift);
        root.children.add(child);
        shift++;
        preIndex += shift;
        postIndex += shift;
    }
    return root;
}
```

Why is the first function defined as public and the second one as private? (I am new to OO programming)

Comment: These are not constructors.

Comment: Class `Node` has no explicit constructors

Comment: Constructor must have no return type, and it's name must be exactly the same as class name.

Comment: You have two overloaded methods and only one of them is exposed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The public one is the interface contract, any caller can use it directly. The private one is the internal implementation, another `Node` implementation can be created and provide the same `public` interface (with a different method implementation). It was an implementation decision and is conceptually covered by [encapsulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29#General_definition) (which Wikipedia says) *is used to hide the values or state of a structured data object inside a class, preventing unauthorized parties' direct access to them*.

Answer (score 0):

As per the Object oriented programming concept, the public buildTree method can be accessible in other classes and packages but the private buildTree method can be used only within the class.